# C Struct Operators

Tags: c, struct

In Deitel's book about C structures, there is a question like this:

```
struct customer {
   char lastName[ 15 ];
   char firstName[ 15 ];
   int customerNumber;
       struct {
           char phoneNumber[ 11 ];
           char address[ 50 ];
           char city[ 15 ];
           char state[ 3 ];
           char zipCode[ 6 ];
           } personal;

 } 
    customerRecord, *customerPtr;
    customerPtr = &customerRecord;
```

and the question is:

Member phoneNumber of member personal of the structure pointed to by customerPtr.?

Answer in solution Manual:

```
 customerRecord->personal.phoneNumber
```

Is the solution right? customerRecord is not a pointer but answer used arrow. I thought the answer must be this:

```
 customerPtr->personal.phoneNumber
```

What confuses me is this is a basic thing and maybe I did not get it right yet.

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

You are correct, it's the pointer to structure (`customerPtr` in your case) that needs the "arrow" operator `->`. The other (`customerRecord`) would use the normal dot-operator.

Comment: What about this, would this work? `(&customerRecord)->personal.phoneNumber`

Comment: @BitFiddlingCodeMonkey Yes that would work, since then you have a pointer to a structure.